# iPodMusicPlayer playbackState goes wrong after queue updates

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm currently developing a music player app and ran into a coulpe of interesting behaviours regarding the the playback states of MPMusicPlayerController:

- when I update the player queue and and set the nowPlayingItem because the music was playing, so I want it to continue. These changes obviously changes playbackStates. But if these updates happen rapidly, after some time (sometimes almost at first), the playbackState goes wrong and it says paused but the music is still playing!
- and an other problem regarding these updates, when I update the queue, set the nowPlaying item and call the play method, I think it should cause 1 or 2 playback state change, but what happens is that the playbackStateDidChange notification gets called 4-5 times quickly. I really don't get why is there so many playback state changes, and I think maybe these causes the playbackState to go wrong.

I would very much appreciate any help!

Thanks